# Grails 2.0.1 does not like java.util.Date

Tags: grails

I updated from Grails 2.0 to 2.0.1 and started getting this error. Any ideas what broke and how to fix it?

> ... The [getTransactionData] action accepts a parameter of type [java.util.Date] which does not appear to be a command object class.  This can happen if the source code for this class is not in this project and the class is not marked with @Validateable.

Comment: "Grails 2.0.1 does not like Java Util Date" .... and who does? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem for a helper method in my controller.  Is your getTransactionData a helper method?  In my case, the problem was solved by changing the method to private, since all public methods are treated as controller actions in Grails 2.0.1+.

Credit, where credit is due:  Jeff Brown's answer on nabble, though it didn't fix the problem for the original question, cured it for me:  http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-0-1-strange-behaviour-td4390405.html.

Comment: Yeah making it private fixed the problem for me. And the problem showed up after I upgraded to 2.0.2 I guessed this was the problem nice to have confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a command object that's in src/groovy? You'll need to annotate it with `@Validateable` - add an import for `grails.validation.Validateable`.

Comment: Its standard Java.util.Date, I was able to get rid of this by making the offending method call private but that may not be possible in other cases